# Average time in which a product random variable becomes zero

Tags: regression, loss-functions, poisson-process, discrete-time, optimal-stopping

Im looking for the optimal time in which a process should be cancelled before it results on financial losses.

Say M_n=X_n*Y_n-c(n) for  for n =1 to 12 which is the number of hours the process gets going, and c(n) is the cost of the process on the n-th hour. c(n) is deterministic in nature as opposed to X_n, a positive real number and Y_n, a count random variable.

I have no background on time series analysis but maybe I could try and apply a linear regression model with time as the independent variable and see on average where, and if, M_n gets equal to zero.

What do you think? Maybe I should treat time as continuous and analyse M_t as a Poisson process?

Comment: Hi: Are $X_n$ and $Y_{n}$ known ? I realize that $Y_n$ is a random variable but it's observed, correct ?

Comment: Yes I have thousands of observations of those two variables but I haven't adjusted any distribution to them though.

Comment: So $X_{n}$ is a random variable also ? It sounds like there are pairs of $X_i, Y_i ~~\forall i = 1 \ldots n. $ Also, do you know $c(n)$ at all $n$ ? I'm still a little confused because you said that you have thousands of observations but $n$ only goes from 1 to 12 ?

Comment: Sorry for my notation I'm a little bit rusty. Indeed, c(n) is known at all n and X_n is also a random variable so it's a product of two random variables, one a count and the other is positive and real valued. As for the number of observations, we get thousands of new records at random times for twelve hours a day. For simplicity we assume each hour is independent from the others so that's why we group the observations hourly.

Comment: Hi Vacoiide: okay. thanks for the info. I'll read it more carefully tomorrow and try to suggest something. But I bet when people read what you said, they will be sending suggestions or answers before I wake up !!!!! It's much clearer now, atleast to me.

Comment: Hi Vacoiide: It's still not totally clear to me. When you subscript by $n$ it seems that that denotes the  hour number that the observation pair came from and there are 12 hours. But when you write X_n, Y_n, they have a monthly subscript but aren't there 1000's of observation pairs for a given $n$. Maybe you need a second subscript on your $X_n$ and $Y_n$ ?

Comment: Hello. Yes! For the purposes of sampling, a second subscript is what I'm missing to represent each day.

Comment: As for the problem itself, my approach now is to treat it as compound poisson process, with Y_t as the number of ocurrences and X_t as the profit of each ocurrence. So my goal would be to find the expected value at time t of said process and compare it to the cost function at said time. What do you think?

Comment: So, is the  relation, $M_n=X_n \times Y_n-c(n)$, the same for each observation in the $n$ th period which would mean that there are really say ~1000 equations, $M_n=X_n \times Y_n-c(n)$  for each $n$. Or, is $Y_n = 1000$ so you just have one equation ?

Comment: It's the first case, the n-th hour of day i is assumed to behave similarly to the n-th hour of the day j, i,j=1,...,730 because we are considering two whole years.

Comment: So, what I would do as a first step, would be to take some value of $n$ and all the pairs of data points that fall in that value of $n$, and just plot the 3d relation. $M_n$ versus ( $X_{n} and $Y_{n}$ in order to see how $M_n$ varies over say the 1000  or so observations in that group.

Comment: Okey, but then how could I make a statistical statement about such behavior? With that mapping you say maybe I can fix in a region I find interesting and maybe give a confidence interval for the mean there?

Comment: yes, I would definitely plot $M_{n}$  ( versus something ) as the first task so that you can get a feel for that value and see if it matches with your intuition.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your suggestion. Since we didn't have the knowlege on compound non homogeneous poisson processes or time series we decided to model only one variable and use averages on the other one and do some old hypothesis testing on each subset of hour

Comment: You're welcome. I have no experience with  non homogeneous poisson processes so I'm glad that you worked it out. All the best.